# Wix VersionNT64 not working

Tags: wix

I am installing some drivers along with a program using wix (WiX v3.10.3 (Stable)).
The drivers installed depend on the machine being 32 or 64 bit.

I have been following a tutorial i found that uses

```
<Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[Not VersionNT64]]></Condition>
```

and

```
<Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[VersionNT64]]></Condition>
```

These dont seem to work as i expected so i created a basic message to test them.

```
    <Condition Message="32 bit"><![CDATA[Not VersionNT64]]></Condition>
```

This should display "32 bit" in a message if the installer is run on a 32 bit machine, which i does not.
It does however display it on a 64 bit machine.

also,

```
<Condition Message="64 bit"><![CDATA[VersionNT64]]></Condition>
```

does not work on either 32 or 64 bit.

Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

followed

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-OS-dependent-install.html#VersionNT64

VersionNT64 stores the number of the version same as VersionNT, so to check for x64 of the a specific version you can do

```
(VersionNT=501) AND (VersionNT64<>501)
```

which is checking for XP but only 32bit

Might have to list out each version:

```
(VersionNT=600) AND (VersionNT64<>600)
(VersionNT=601) AND (VersionNT64<>601)
```

ect.

If you only care about x64

```
(VersionNT=VersionNT64)
```

Will be true of x64

Comment: Amazingly weird history of an answer. But it is an answer now. I do not need to understand everything. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Condition/@Message` results in an inverted test to behavior relationship from `Condition/@Level`. The resulting [LaunchCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369752.aspx) entry from `@Message` contains a condition described as:

> Expression that must evaluate to True for installation to begin.

As the condition `Not VersionNT64` is true on 32-bit systems so the installation is allowed to continue. It's false on 64-bit systems, so the installation is blocked and the message should be shown. The condition `VersionNT64` is true only on 64-bit systems, so should have the reverse behavior; it's unclear what you meant by "does not work".